# Between JSON, dictionary and the object of the difference?

Tags: javascript

Distinguish between JSON, dictionary and the object of the difference?

```
 var json = {"a": 1};
 var object = {'a': 1};
 var dic = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Comment: Every language have their own terminologies. You can call it `dict` in python and `object` in JS. You can also call it `List` in C#. Also `dic` in your code is an array

Answer (score 0):

JSON represents JS object -> same as *dictionary* (iOS dev?)